# ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection, and NullReferenceException:

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Problem: Whenver I start my level and draw a line, first time I draw I get the error mentioned below. When I draw again the script works fine without giving any error. Kindly if someone can look into this and help out it'll be great! I've been stuck on this problem for a few days no...
This one when my mouse is pressed:

> ```
>  ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>  non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>  index System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException
>  (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource)
>  (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
>  System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () (at
>  <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) (at
>   <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0) DrawingManager.DrawVisibleLine
>    () (at Assets/2DPhysicsDraw/Scripts/DrawingManager.cs:401)
>    DrawingManager.Update () (at
>    Assets/2DPhysicsDraw/Scripts/DrawingManager.cs:219)
> ```

This one when my I release the mouse,

> ```
>    NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>    object DrawingManager.Update () (at
>    Assets/2DPhysicsDraw/Scripts/DrawingManager.cs:274)
> ```

Awake Method:

> ```
>    private void Awake()
>     {
>     startMoving = false;
>     drawCount = 0;
>     if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
>     {
>         //Destroy(this.gameObject);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         _instance = this;
>     }
>     }
> ```

Start Method:

> ```
>  void Start()
> {
>     DestroyLastPath();
>     startMoving = false;
>     canDraw = true;
>   // Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision( 8, 3 ,true);
>     Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(LayerMask.NameToLayer("OnDraw"),
>     LayerMask.NameToLayer("OnDraw"));
>     mousePointer = GameObject.Find("MousePointer");
>     cloneNumber = 0;
>     //colorStart = Color.black;
>    // colorEnd = Color.black;
>   //  widthStart = 0.2f;
>    // widthEnd = 0.2f;
>     verticesDistance = 0.1f;
>   //  lifeTime = 2f;
>     colliderType = ColliderTypeChoices.Polygon_Collider;
>   //  isPermanent = true;
>   //  fixedPosition = false;
>     showMassCenter = false;
>     massCenterPrecision = 100;
>     dynamicMass = true;
>     massScale = 1f;
>     gravityScale = 1f;
>  //   overlapHandling = overlapHandlingChoices.Follow_The_Edge;
>     freezeWhileDrawing = true;
>
>     tagsCantdraw = tagCantDraw.Split(',');
>     //tagCantDraw
>     
>     
>     pathLineRenderer = path.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
>     //pathRigidbody = path.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
>     pathLineRenderer.useWorldSpace = false;
>
>     // Setting up material of the line, it can be modified or placed as public so it can be changed in inspector
>     // *Obs: changing the material will be facilitated in the next release of the asset
>   //  pathLineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended Premultiply"));
>
>     pathLineRenderer.SetColors(colorStart, colorEnd);
>     pathLineRenderer.SetWidth(widthStart, widthEnd);
>     posCount = 0;
> }
> ```

FixedUpdate Method:

> ```
>  void FixedUpdate()
> {
>     mousePointer.GetComponent<TargetJoint2D>().target = 
>  (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
> }
>
> public void StartVehicle()
> {
>     StartCar.SetActive(true);
> }
> ```

Update Method:

> ```
>    void Update()
>     {
>      canDraw = true;
>         
>     // hit detection by mouse position for the on drawing collision handling
>     if (overlapHandling == overlapHandlingChoices.Cut_After_Collision)
>         hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePointer.transform.position, Vector2.zero, 
>      Mathf.Infinity, layerMask);
>
>     // mouseRay detects if the mouse is over some object
>     mouseRay = 
>       Physics2D.Raycast((Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition),
>       Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask);
>     
>     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
>     {
>       //  PathMaterial.color = Pathcolor[GameManager.EnvirenmentNo - 1];
>         FreezeMoving.freeze = true;
>
>         // disables the drawing when click on objects with the tag "Wall"
>         foreach (string tag in tagsCantdraw)
>         {
>             if (mouseRay.collider != null && mouseRay.collider.tag == tag) 
>                 canDraw = false;
>         }
>         if (GraphicRaycasterRaycasterExample.Instance.candraw == false)
>         {
>             canDraw = false;
>         }
>
>         if (canDraw == true)
>         {
>             mousePointer.transform.position = 
>         Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
>             if (overlapHandling == overlapHandlingChoices.Follow_The_Edge)
>                 Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision( 9, 8 ,true);
>                 mousePointer.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().isTrigger = false;
>
>             mousePointer.transform.localScale = new Vector3(widthEnd, widthEnd, widthEnd);
>             canDraw = true;
>             StarPrefab();
>             centerOfMassCount = 0;
>             centerOfMass = Vector2.zero;
>         }
>     }
>
>     if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
>     {
>         if (canDraw == true)
>         {
>             Particle.SetActive(true);
>             // if collides, sets collision handing flag
>             if (hit.collider != null)
>             {
>                 mouseHit = true;
>                
>             }
>
>             canDraw = true;
>             DrawVisibleLine();
>             
>            
>            
>         }
>     }
>     if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
>     {
>         FreezeMoving.freeze = false;
>         Particle.SetActive(false);
>         if (canDraw == true)
>         {
>             mousePointer.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().isTrigger = true;
>             mouseHit = false;
>
>
>             if (colliderType == ColliderTypeChoices.Edge_Collider)
>             {
>                 newVerticies.Add(mousePointer.transform.position - 
>          clone.transform.position);
>                 Debug.Log("currently in if");
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 Debug.Log("Currently in esleeee");
>                 newVerticies2.Clear();
>                 newVerticies.Add(mousePointer.transform.position);
>                 for (int i = 0; i < newVerticies.Count - 1; i++)
>                 {
>                     if (i < newVerticies.Count - 2)
>                     {
>                         // calculates the angle of each edge in the line
>                         colliderAngle = Mathf.Atan2(newVerticies[i].y - newVerticies[i + 
>           1].y,
>          newVerticies[i].x - newVerticies[i + 1].x);
>                         colliderAngle = colliderAngle + (Mathf.Deg2Rad * 90f);
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                         // Since we have two points to have an edge and the last point is 
>             not in this for, the angle calculation is
>            not 
>                         // done for the last edge and the same angel from befor is preserved
>                     }
>                     float cos = Mathf.Cos(colliderAngle);   // calc cos
>                     float sin = Mathf.Sin(colliderAngle);   // calc sin
>
>                     // Get the width of the line for each point of it
>                     float tempWidth = Mathf.Lerp(widthStart, widthEnd, (float)i / 
>            (newVerticies.Count - 2));
>
>                     // To make the Polygon Collider 2D go around the line, it means each 
>           side of the line,
>                     // adds one point to the beginning and one to the end of the List
>                     newVerticies2.Add(new Vector2(
>                                     (newVerticies[i].x) + ((tempWidth / 2) * cos),
>                                     (newVerticies[i].y) + ((tempWidth / 2) * sin)));
>                     newVerticies2.Insert(0, new Vector2(
>                                     (newVerticies[i].x) - ((tempWidth / 2) * cos),
>                                     (newVerticies[i].y) - ((tempWidth / 2) * sin)));
>
>                 }
>                 pathPolygonCollider.points = newVerticies2.ToArray();
>                 pathPolygonCollider.sharedMaterial = material;
>             }
>             CalculatesPrevCenterOfMassAndMass(newVerticies.Count - 1);
>             clone.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Drawing");
>             pathLineRenderer.SetVertexCount(newVerticies.Count - 1);
>             for (int i = 0; i < newVerticies.Count - 1; i++)
>             {
>
>                 pathLineRenderer.SetPosition(i, newVerticies[i]);
>
>             }
>
>             if (dynamicMass == true)
>                 pathRigidbody.mass *= massScale;
>             else pathRigidbody.mass = massScale;
>             centerOfMass /= centerOfMassCount;
>             if (newVerticies.Count > 2 && (widthStart != 0 || widthEnd != 0))
>                 pathRigidbody.centerOfMass = centerOfMass;
>
>             // Check if you want to show the center of mass during the gameplay and 
>            instantiate the prefab in the proper position
>             // *Obs: the MassCenter prefab can be personalized with an image or anything you 
>             want to show the center of mass
>             if (showMassCenter)
>             {
>                 massCenterClone = (GameObject)Instantiate(massCenter, 
>             this.transform.position,
>              Quaternion.identity);
>                 massCenterClone.transform.parent = pathRigidbody.transform;
>                 massCenterClone.transform.position = centerOfMass;
>             }
>
>             pathRigidbody.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic;
>             posCount = 0;
>              
>             // Check if the drawn line is too small or if it doesn't have visual volume and 
>             destroy the prefab if it true
>             /*if (newVerticies.Count <= 2 || (widthStart == 0 && widthEnd == 0))
>             {
>                 cloneNumber--;
>                 Destroy(clone);
>             }*/
>         }
>         canDraw = true;
>         drawCount++;
>         Debug.Log(drawCount);
>         FreezeMoving.freeze = false;
>         // if set to freeze the drawn objects while drawing a new one and is not set to be 
>          fixed position, 
>         // it adds the script FreezeMoving to the new drawings so it freezes when 
>            FreezeMoving.freeze variable is true
>         if (fixedPosition == false && clone)
>         {
>             clone.gameObject.AddComponent<FreezeMoving>();
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             if (pathRigidbody != null)
>             {
>                 pathRigidbody.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Static;
>             }
>         }
>         Invoke(nameof(StartVehicle),1.5f);
>         
>     }
>
> }
> ```

DestroyLastPathMethod:

> ```
>   public void DestroyLastPath()
> {
>     if (paths.Count > 0)
>     {
>         Destroy(paths[paths.Count - 1]);
>         paths.RemoveAt(paths.Count - 1);
>     }
>    
>    
> }
> ```

StarPrefab Method:

> ```
>  /// <summary>
> /// Instantiate prefab and initialize necessary variables for the drawing construction
> /// </summary>
>
> void StarPrefab()
> {
>     canDraw = true;
>     clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(path, mousePointer.transform.position, 
>       Quaternion.identity); // instantiate
>        prefab
>     clone.name = "Drawing" + cloneNumber;
>     paths.Add(clone);
>         // Rename instantiated object so it can be easyli tracked
>     cloneNumber++;                                          // Add 1 in the variable for 
>         renaming the drawings
>     pathLineRenderer = clone.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
>     pathRigidbody = clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
>     pathRigidbody.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;                       // Set 
>         rigidbody kinematic so it wont move during the drawing process
>     pathRigidbody.gravityScale = gravityScale;              // Adjust gravity for the 
>           drawing
>     clone.transform.position = Vector3.zero; // Camera.main.transform.position - new
>          Vector3(0,0,Camera.main.transform.position.z);
>     clone.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
>     pathRigidbody.centerOfMass = Vector2.zero;              // Initialize center of mass 
>        before calculating the real position
>     pathLineRenderer.SetColors(colorStart, colorEnd);       // Set colors
>     pathLineRenderer.SetWidth(widthStart, widthEnd);        // width
>     newVerticies.Clear();                                   // Clear Lists before adding new 
>        points for the new drawing
>     newVerticies_.Clear();
>     newVerticies2.Clear();                                  // This is the List used to 
>           create the Polygon Collider 2D
>     pathLineRenderer.SetVertexCount(1);                     // Add one position spot so it 
>        can add the first point of the Drawing
>     pathLineRenderer.SetPosition(0, mousePointer.transform.position - new
>       Vector3(0,0,Camera.main.transform.position.z)); // Add first point in
>          the Line Renderer
>
>     newVerticies.Add(mousePointer.transform.position - clone.transform.position); // Add 
>             first point to the array used to
>         create the Colliders
>     newVerticies_.Add(mousePointer.transform.position - clone.transform.position);
>
>     // Check if the chosen collider is Edge or Polygon and destroy the one is not going to 
>            be used
>     if (colliderType == ColliderTypeChoices.Edge_Collider)
>     {
>         Destroy(clone.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>());
>         pathEdgeCollider = clone.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         Destroy(clone.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>());
>         pathPolygonCollider = clone.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
>         pathPolygonCollider.points = newVerticies2.ToArray(); // Bugfix: when creating a new 
>            drawing, collider was created in the
>         center of the scene and hit some objects
>          }
>          }
> ```

Drawline Method:

> ```
>    /// <summary>
> /// Draw the line using mouse position and adding the points to the Line Renderer
> /// </summary>
>
> void DrawVisibleLine()
> {
>     canDraw = true;
>     Debug.Log("drawinggggggggggggggg");
>     // Check if the minimun distance (verticesDistance) from the previous vertice is reached 
>         and add the next point
>     if (Vector2.Distance(mousePointer.transform.position, newVerticies_[posCount]) >= 
>            verticesDistance || 
>         Vector2.Distance(mousePointer.transform.position, newVerticies_[posCount]) <= 
>              verticesDistance
>         )
>     {
>       
>         
>         posCount++;
>         pathLineRenderer.SetVertexCount(posCount + 1);
>         pathLineRenderer.SetPosition(posCount, mousePointer.transform.position - new 
>              Vector3(0, 0,
>            Camera.main.transform.position.z));
>         Particle.transform.position = mousePointer.transform.position - new Vector3(0, 0,
>          Camera.main.transform.position.z);
>         newVerticies_.Add(mousePointer.transform.position - clone.transform.position);
>         if (mouseHit == false)
>         {
>             newVerticies.Add(mousePointer.transform.position - clone.transform.position);
>
>             // Check the chosen collider
>             if (colliderType == ColliderTypeChoices.Edge_Collider)
>             {
>                 //for (int i = 0; i < newVerticies.Count - 1; i++)
>                 //{
>                 //    // Get the width of the line for each point of it
>                 //    float tempWidth = Mathf.Lerp(widthStart, widthEnd, (float)i / 
>              (newVerticies.Count - 2));
>                 //    
>                 //}
>                 if (newVerticies.Count > 2)
>                     pathEdgeCollider.points = newVerticies.ToArray();
>                 pathEdgeCollider.sharedMaterial = material;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 newVerticies2.Clear();
>                 newVerticies.Add(mousePointer.transform.position - 
>               clone.transform.position);
>                 for (int i = 0; i < newVerticies.Count - 1; i++)
>                 {
>
>                     // calculates the angle of each edge in the line
>                     colliderAngle = Mathf.Atan2(newVerticies[i].y - newVerticies[i + 1].y, 
>                 newVerticies[i].x - newVerticies[i + 1].x);
>                     colliderAngle = colliderAngle + (Mathf.Deg2Rad * 90f);
>
>
>                     float cos = Mathf.Cos(colliderAngle);   // calc cos
>                     float sin = Mathf.Sin(colliderAngle);   // calc sin
>
>                     // Get the width of the line for each point of it
>                     float tempWidth = Mathf.Lerp(widthStart, widthEnd, (float)i / 
>                 (newVerticies.Count - 2));
>
>                     // To make the Polygon Collider 2D go around the line, it means each 
>                   side of the line,
>                     // adds one point to the beginning and one to the end of the List
>                     newVerticies2.Add(new Vector2(
>                                     (newVerticies[i].x) + ((tempWidth / 2) * cos),
>                                     (newVerticies[i].y) + ((tempWidth / 2) * sin)));
>                     newVerticies2.Insert(0, new Vector2(
>                                     (newVerticies[i].x) - ((tempWidth / 2) * cos),
>                                     (newVerticies[i].y) - ((tempWidth / 2) * sin)));
>                     
>                 }
>                 newVerticies.RemoveAt(newVerticies.Count - 1);
>                 pathPolygonCollider.points = newVerticies2.ToArray();
>                 pathPolygonCollider.sharedMaterial = material;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     
> }
> ```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't know your line numbers ... double click on the errors in Unity or click the blue links they will directly bring you to the according code line ... I would start checking if `posCount` is valid in `newVerticies_[posCount]`

Comment: And for the NullRef your Update method you post is way to complex and we don't know what line `274` is ... but look into your code at line `274` what could possibly be `null` .. then find out why this is the case ;)

Comment: Hi @derHugo sir, this is the line 274,   pathPolygonCollider.points = newVerticies2.ToArray();

Comment: I tried debugging as well but cant seem to find the issue as it works just fine after i get this error once.

Comment: well then either `pathPolygonCollider` or `newVerticies2` is `null` in that moment .. now find out why this is the case. Where are they assigned? Is i sure that this line is never being executed before these are assigned correctly? It is quite hard to tell as your code snippet is really cluttered .. it is neither a Minimal example nor the entire code .. but something in between which isn't really helpful :)

Comment: These are the lines 219 and 401 respectively,    219: DrawVisibleLine(); , 4101:   if (Vector2.Distance(mousePointer.transform.position, newVerticies_[posCount]) >= verticesDistance || 
            Vector2.Distance(mousePointer.transform.position, newVerticies_[posCount]) <= verticesDistance
            )

Comment: I'm sorry should i post the function in which this is happening instead?

Comment: You should post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code ... however, in your case this might be quite difficult to achieve since you seem to not even know what is possibly related to the error and what not. All we can ell you from here is that either `pathPolygonCollider` or `newVerticies2` is `null` in that moment and that `posCount` is either `< 0` or `>= newVerticies_.Count` ... the **why** you will have to figure out yourself I guess or somehow provide the complete code ^^

Comment: I'll try to see if pathpolygonCollider/ newvertices2 is null, if I find something then I'll let you know sir @derHugo

Comment: @derHugo So when I click the first time the vertices are not added in either newverticies_ or newverticies2 and I want my mousehit/ when I click on screen to add vertices to these two lists. I can share code with you if you say so :(

Comment: @derHugo actually, when I go to my level from the main menu like when i turn on the game and start a level this works fine. The line is drawn on first touch. But when I restart or go to the next level (I have used the restart logic on next level) it doesnt work first time and gives these two errors: Error 1: ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (on lines 415 and 220) and the second error, Error2: NullReferenceException: (on line 277)